# how do I replace one word found many places under one class with javascript?

Tags: javascript, replace, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension to redesign the tumblr dashboard for a project.

This is a small thing but has been very frustrating. I want to get rid of the word "notes" after the number of notes bellow each post.

The string is under a class .note_link_current so I tried this

```
var textNotes = $('.note_link_current').text();
textNotes = textNotes.replace('notes', ' ');
$('.note_link_current').text(textNotes);
```

What seems to happen is that I get a combined string of all the notes of all the posts.. How do I get it so it affects all of them individually?

Right now I'm getting something like this:

```
251 
                63 notes441 notes74 notes851 notes49,263 notes2,561 notes142 notes1 note651 notes
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `->` http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @FelixKling said, but with more explanation:

A jQuery selector like `$('.note_link_current')` will return an array of nodes. You're trying to make an operation on this array like it was one node.

Instead, what you should do is invoke `.each()`, to perform an operation on every element.

```
$('.note_link_current').each( function(index) {
  // Inside this function, "this" refers to the (DOM) element selected
  var text = $(this).text();
  /* ... */
});
```